# Excel Sumif Array- works in sheet returns false in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sumifs

I have a question regarding the sumif array function in excel.

My current formula works perfectly when typed to a cell and used as a array  Ctrl + Shift + Enter  and the filled down the column with the double click.

the formula is `=SUMIFS(T:T,A:A,A2,C:C,"<"&OFFSET($H$1,MATCH(1,(A:A=A2)*(H:H=[IPE.xlsm]Overview!$C$3),0),-5))`

My problem is when I try to integrate this formula into my current vba script.

Below is the section where Im running into this error.

when the code is run it returns a false statement, again though if I copy paste the formula it returns the correct value.

```
Sub Enter_Array_Formulas()

    Range("W2").FormulaArray = "=SUMIFS(T:T,A:A,A2,C:C," < "&
    OFFSET($H$1,MATCH (1,(A:A=A2)*(H:H=[IPE.xlsm]Overview!$C$3),0),-5))"

    Range("U2").Select

    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 0).Select
    Selection.FillDown


    End Sub
```

Im guessing its a syntax error but I'm unable to find the hiccup.

Thanks in advance,

Ross

Comment: Also, try removing the space around the `<` in your formula: `...C:C, "<"&...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Range("W2").FormulaArray = "=SUMIFS(T:T,A:A,A2,C:C,""<""&OFFSET($H$1,MATCH(1,(A:A=A2)*(H:H=[IPE.xlsm]Overview!$C$3),0),-5))"
```

You need to be careful when using speech marks in strings -- use two `""` instead

Also, you entered a blank space after `MATCH`, which would be corrected for you on the worksheet but probably just throws an error in VBA.

Comment: No real need for concatenating there: `Range("W2").FormulaArray = "=SUMIFS(T:T,A:A,A2,C:C,""<""&OFFSET($H$1,MATCH(1,(A:A=A2)*(H:H=[IPE.xlsm]Overview!$C$3),0),-5))"`

Comment: Thanks @Rory - was trying that but gave up trying to make it work (possibly because there was still a space after the match). Updated :)

Comment: You do need the `&` after the `""<""` as it's actually part of the formula.

Comment: Made the change too quickly! Thanks

Comment: The extra set of quotes around the "<" did the trick! So to clarify this is needed when transfer/writing the formula in VBA?

Comment: @Ross.P  You tell me?